# "Access denied for user" error when creating a procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions, procedure-definition

When I request my database server (MySQL), with `"show grants for current_user"`

I notice that I have the grant to execute procedure:

```
SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE
```

But when I execute a sql file that contains those instructions :

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS
CREATE FUNCTION 
CREATE PROCEDURE
DECLARE
CALL
```

I have this error :

```
ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 16: Access denied for user
```

The line 16 contains : `CREATE FUNCTION function_name( .. )`

Should I have other grants ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From  [MySQL Documention:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-routine)

> The CREATE ROUTINE privilege is needed to create stored routines (procedures and functions).

Example:

```
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON yourDB.* TO youUser;
```

Max